# Placing the jar in eclipse plugin folder is not working as expected

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins

I tried to download secure assist plugin from eclipse market space but no luck .It started throwing multiple error out of that one is as follows.

> ```
>     An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
>
>     > session context was:(profile=DefaultProfile,
>     > phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=,
>     > action=)
>     > No repository found containing:
>     > osgi.bundle,com.ibm.icu,54.1.1.v201501272100
> ```

I manually pasted the dependency jars from eclipse plugin folder from other machine and restarted the eclipse.After doing that
also its not working.Any idea to get rid of this. ***I don't want to change eclipse*** version.Any help would be appreciated.
I use ***STS 3.6.1*** release

```
Thanks
Pradeep
```

Comment: You can't just put things in the Eclipse plugin directory, they have to be properly installed for the Eclipse P2 install system to know about them.

Comment: I agree with you Greg.When I tried to download from eclipse site it shows repository not found and some weird errors which is untraceable .If you want I can share the error logs as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to their web site STS 3.6.1 is based on Eclipse 4.4.0. This only has version 52 of com.ibm.icu.

ICU 54 first appears in Eclipse 4.5.2 so you will need to update to at least STS 3.7.2 but you would probably be better updating to the current release 3.8.4 base on the current stable Eclipse Neon.3 (4.6.3).

Comment: If that's the only option then I will update the sts and see.Thanks for the inputs.